# My LINQ count query returns the wrong result

Tags: javascript, linq.js

I'm using linq.js to use LINQ in my JavaScript code.  When trying to filter out an array, I'm getting a bogus output. What am I doing wrong?

**Code:**

```
console.log($.Enumerable.From(streams.Medias["User Feeds"][a].Streams).Where('x => x.Name.length > 0').Count);
```

**Output (in the browser console):**

```
function (a){a=a==b?g.True:d.CreateLambda(a);var c=0;this.ForEach(function(d,b){if(a(d,b))++c});return c}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Count` is a function.  You must call it to get the value.

```
var count = $.Enumerable.From(streams.Medias["User Feeds"][a].Streams)
    .Where('x => x.Name.length > 0')
    .Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget it,
solved it using jquery $.grep which does the same thing.